# How does bash differentiate between brace expansion and command grouping?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've noticed that `{` can be used in brace expansion:

```
echo {1..8}
```

or in command grouping:

```
{ls;echo hi}
```

How does bash know the difference?

Comment: Excellent question, +1. It seems like it might be that `{` is interpreted as a command list if it appears at the beginning of a command and as a brace expansion otherwise, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `{ls;echo hi}` isn't legal `bash`. You need a space after the opening brace and a semicolon before the closing one.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A simplified reason is the existence of one character: <kbd>space</kbd>.

Brace expansions do not process (un-quoted) spaces.

A `{...}` list needs (un-quoted) spaces.

The more detailed answer is [how the shell parses a command line](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html).

---

The first step to parse (understand) a command line is to divide it into parts.
These parts (usually called words or tokens) result from dividing a command line at each meta-character [from the link](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html):

> 1. Splits the command into tokens that are separated by the fixed set of meta-characters: SPACE, TAB, NEWLINE, ;, (, ), <, >, |, and &. Types of tokens include words, keywords, I/O redirectors, and semicolons.

Meta-characters: <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>|</kbd> and <kbd>&</kbd>.

After splitting, words may be of a type (as understood by the shell):

- Command pre-asignements: `LC=ALL ...`
- Command                 `LC=ALL echo`
- Arguments                 `LC=ALL echo "hello"`
- Redirection                 `LC=ALL echo "hello" >&2`

---

## Brace expansion

Only if a "brace string" (without spaces or meta-characters) is a single word (as described above) and is **not quoted**, it is a candidate for "Brace expansion". More checks are performed on the internal structure later.

Thus, this: `{ls,-l}` qualifies as "Brace expansion" to become `ls -l`, either as `first word` or `argument` (in bash, zsh is different).

```
$ {ls,-l}            ### executes `ls -l`
$ echo {ls,-l}       ### prints `ls -l`
```

But this will not: `{ls ,-l}`. Bash will split on <kbd>space</kbd> and parse the line as two words: `{ls` and `,-l}` which will trigger a `command not found` (the argument `,-l}` is lost):

```
 $ {ls ,-l}
 bash: {ls: command not found
```

Your line: `{ls;echo hi}` will not become a "Brace expansion" because of the **two** meta-characters <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd>.

It will be broken into this three parts: `{ls` new command: `echo` `hi}`. Understand that the <kbd>;</kbd> triggers the start of a new command. The command `{ls` will not be found, and the next command will print `hi}`:

```
$ {ls;echo hi}
bash: {ls: command not found
hi}
```

If it is placed after some other command, it will anyway start a new command after the <kbd>;</kbd>:

```
$ echo {ls;echo hi}
{ls
hi}
```

---

## List

One of the "compound commands" is a "Brace List" (my words): `{ list; }`.
As you can see, it is defined with spaces and a closing `;`.
The spaces and <kbd>;</kbd> are needed because both `{` and `}` are "Reserved **Words**".

And therefore, to be recognized as words, must be surrounded by meta-characters (almost always: <kbd>space</kbd>).

As described in the point 2 of [the linked page](http://helios.cs.ifmo.ru/~ad/Documentation/Bash_Shell/bash3-CHP-7-SECT-3.html)

> 2. Checks the first token of each command to see if it is .... , {, or (, then the command is actually a compound command.

Your example: `{ls;echo hi}` is not a list.

It needs a closing <kbd>;</kbd> and one space (at least) after <kbd>{</kbd>. The last <kbd>}</kbd> is defined by the closing <kbd>;</kbd>.

This is a list `{ ls;echo hi; }`. And this `{ ls;echo hi;}` is also (less commonly used, but valid)(Thanks @choroba for the help).

```
$ { ls;echo hi; }
A-list-of-files
hi
```

But as argument (the shell knows the difference) to a command, it triggers an error:

```
$ echo { ls;echo hi; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

But be careful in what you believe the shell is parsing:

```
$ echo { ls;echo hi;
{ ls
hi
```

Comment: this is really the best answer, because you give us indeed how bash parser works !  and with an detail explanation !

Comment: You don't need the space between `;` and `}`. `{ ls;}` works as the semicolon is already a meta-character.

Comment: @lovespring Thanks, yes I invested some time in writting it. I am happy to know that it is useful. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 16):

The block `{` is a shell keyword, so it must separated from the next word by space, while in brace expansion, there should be no space (if you need to brace expand a space, you have to escape it: `echo {\ ,a}{b,c}`).

You can use brace expansion at the start of a command:

```
{ls,.}  # expands to "ls ."
```

You can't use it to expand to a block, though, as parsing of the grouping commands happens before expansions:

```
echo {'{ ls','.;}'}  # { ls .;}
{'{ ls','.;}'}       # bash: { ls: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5):

It knows by checking the syntax of the command line. In the same way it knows that in the expression `echo echo`, the first echo should be treated as a command and the second echo as a parameter of the first echo.

In bash it is very simple, since `{ cmd; }` should have spaces and semicolon. However, for example in zsh they are not needed, but still by analyzing context of `{}` shell is able to tell what should be done with its content.

Consider the following:

```
alias 1..3=date
{ 1..3; }    #in bash
{1..3}       #in zsh
```

Both return current date, but

```
echo {1..3}
```

returns `1 2 3` because shell knows `{}` in an argument for command `echo`, so should be expanded.

Comment: `{` followed by unquoted space doesn't start brace expansion in bash.

Comment: @choroba Yes, and not only right after `{`. Unquoted space cannot be anywhere because shell splits entire command line on spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a the compound brace must be a word by itself and the first word of the command line:

```
echo { these braces are just words }
```

Secondly, individual braces are not special (as you can see above). Empty braces are also not special:

```
echo {} # just the token {}: familiar from the find command
```

Anything without commas is also just itself

```
echo {abc} # just {abc}
```

Here is where the action starts.

```
echo {a,b} # braces disappear, a b results.
```

So basically for brace expansion to kick in, we need a single word (not separated into fields on whitespace), inside of which there occurs at least one instance of `{...}` inside of which there occurs at least one comma.

This **can** be the first word in the command line, by the way:

```
{ls,-l} .   # just "ls -l ."
```