# How to insert comma at given location?

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have a text file that's over 100MB, each line of which has the same number of columns:

```
Column No.: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
            d x c c s b c
            .............
```

I want to add `,` at given locations. For example, `location = 2, 3, 5`

The desired output would be:

```
Column No.:  0 1 2  3  4 5  6
             d x c, c, s b, c
             .............
```

The location file would be a *text* or *csv* file

```
2
3
5
```

The text file has to have delimiters.

Update:

Sample data

[image]

- Note: the line breaks are where I want to put delimiters
- Column No. is the byte offset from the beginning of the line

Comment: It's unclear if the input file "*Column No.*" refers to bytes, (the 6th column `c` would be the 7th byte of the file), or spaced delimited columns of strings, (the 6th column `c` would the the 13th byte).

Comment: @agc I attached a sample data

Comment: The question doesn't specify whether every line in the 100MB input file has the same number of columns.

Comment: @agc I confirm evert line has same number of columns.

Comment: @agc Any other conditions that I need to explain?

Comment: So would it be correct to say that given the image of the sample data, that in line #1, column #6 would be `2` and column #7 would be `4`?  Also after the image of the sample data, "*line breaks*" refers to those vertical black lines?

Comment: Actually considering the number of commas you need to add, you probably *should* use brace expansion as included in the addendum to my answer.  It will make the code clearer to read.

Comment: @agc Yes for both questions. In the answer below, it starts from 1 rather 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use Sed.**

Note that you won't be using 0 indexed positions, but starting from 1.  So I've incremented the numbers you gave.

Also, you have to go back to front since once you change the first one, the column positions change.  So use Sed like so:

```
sed 's/./&,/6;s/./&,/4;s/./&,/3'
```

Example:

```
$ echo dxccsbc
dxccsbc
$ echo dxccsbc | sed 's/./&,/6;s/./&,/4;s/./&,/3'
dxc,c,sb,c
$
```

---

- The `s` command in Sed is for substitution.
- The pattern `.` matches any single character.
- The `&` in the replacement text means "the text that was matched," and the comma is a literal comma.
- The numerical flag after the last `/` means to only perform the substitution on the "nth" match on the line.

---

If you want to be *really* fancy, use Bash brace expansion to create the Sed commands:

```
$ echo dxccsbc | sed '-es/./&,/'{6,4,3}
dxc,c,sb,c
```

But that's just icing on the cake and probably confusing unless you understand both Sed and Bash quite well.  :)

---

**If you want to pull the list of positions from a separate file** (as you actually show in your question), you can do this like so:

```
sed -f <(sort -rn positionsfile | sed -n 's:^[1-9][0-9]*$:s/./\&,/&:p') file
```

Note this is Bash-specific as it uses process substitution syntax that is not POSIX.  Also note I've made this quite robust as anything but actual *numbers* in the positionsfile (that don't start with 0) will be discarded.

Test results:

```
$ cat file 
abcdefg
ABCDEFG
abcdelaksjdflkjsdflli
sdlfihsdlfkj
$ cat positionsfile 
2
15
5
7something
01
not a number
$ sed -f <(sort -rn positionsfile | sed -n 's:^[1-9][0-9]*$:s/./\&,/&:p') file
ab,cde,fg
AB,CDE,FG
ab,cde,laksjdflkj,sdflli
sd,lfi,hsdlfkj
$
```

Comment: Good answer. I can never remember the syntax for these complex substitutions. Could you elaborate on the brace expansion method? Also, do you know if the syntax is the same for `perl`?

Comment: @tjt263, you can read up on Brace Expansion either [on this site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254494/135943) or in the Bash man page at `LESS='+/^ *brace expansion' man bash`  I don't know about Perl but I doubt the syntax is the same.

Comment: I understand typical `bash` style expansion. Something about it in this context seems unusual.

Comment: @tjt263, since the brace expansion results will each be separate arguments, it's necessary to put the `-e` flag for Sed at the beginning so that it doesn't interpret them as files named `s/./&,/4` and `s/./&,/3`.  But no need for a space between `-e` and the Sed command following it, so it works out nicely.  I'll grant that it is indeed an unusual use of brace expansion.  :)  (Also you should understand that Sed never sees the single quotes surrounding any command passed to it; those are purely for the shell.)

Comment: Inelegant addition to the *really fancy* code above, which parses the *location* input file also: `eval "echo dxccsbc | sed '-es/./&,/'"$(tac location | numprocess /+1/ | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/}/;s/.*/{&/')`; or assuming there's a data file for input:  `eval "sed '-es/./&,/'"$(tac location | numprocess /+1/ | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/}/;s/.*/{&/') input.txt`

Comment: Excellent. It's a tricky one. I was conflicted. On one hand, I felt like the quotes ought to envelope the braces to keep from splitting. On the other hand, I was fairly certain that would inhibit the expansion.

Comment: @agc, nice and tricky.  :)  See update.  I have never needed to use `eval` for anything and I have always found a better solution.  You can read from a positions file using process substitution, with some sorting and filtering thrown in.

Comment: Neat update -- it's almost there, but that last non-`eval` code needs to add one to each number in `positionsfile`.

Comment: Non-`eval` and no `bash`isms:  `sed $( echo $(sort -rn positionsfile | numprocess /+1/ ) | sed -n 's:[1-9][0-9]*:s/./\&,/&\;:g;s/\; /\;/gp') file`.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my @pos;

while (<>)
    { push @pos, 1 + int; }
continue
    { last if eof; }

@pos = sort { $b cmp $a } @pos;

while (<>) {
    for my $k (@pos)
        { s/^.{$k}\K/,/; }
    print;
}
```

Run it like this:

```
script.pl positions.txt file.txt
```